# Can I add Active Directory to Team Foundation Server afterwards

Tags: tfs, active-directory

I've been wanting to use Team Foundation Server at work. We have a MSDN subscription that includes TFS. The company has a server here at my current location that is not on the company network but has access to the internet (it's own internet connection with a static IP) I'm curious if it is possible to set me and the other developer up with a temporary account on TFS2013 so that we can use the server while it is still here. Then when it gets moved to its new home and gets added to the domain that we can just delete our temporary account access so that we can use our active directory accounts.

Is this something that is doable? Since I don't know much about networking in general I'm not sure if what I'm asking is even doable. If so where can I find documentation about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use it without a domain, but migrating it to a domain later is a tricky process.

To use without it on the domain, just create local accounts on the TFS server, then when you try to connect and get prompted provide the credentials for the local TFS account.

However, if you plan to put it on the domain later I would **strongly** recommend putting it on the domain to begin with.

If you do need to move a server between domains (or take a non-domain server and join a domain), this MSDN article explains the process: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404883.aspx

Comment: What ends up being the tricky part? I thought I saw in the setup a "easy" way of connecting my active directory things. But not being a server guy I'm not sure...

Comment: All the identities and SID's become invalid once it joins a new/different domain.  I'll link the relevant MSDN article into my answer and you can judge for yourself.