# Configure Authentication for actual html login page

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-server-2019

We've got an install of Azure Devops server that currently authenticates against our active directory server and authentication works, but it appears to do so by means of browser basic authentication (the browser modal prompt that asks for a simple user name and password).

I'm wondering if there is some way to configure authentication such that users that have never logged in, actually get a login page... not just the basic authentication prompt in the browser.

I appreciate any input, I've used and administered azure devops in the cloud for a LONG time, but the devops server stuff I'm new to.

**NOTE:** I've played with IIS settings for authentication (enabling and disabling basic authentication and forms auth etc, but nothing really seemed to help there)

Answer (score 0):

> it appears to do so by means of browser basic authentication (the
>   browser modal prompt that asks for a simple user name and password).
>
> I'm wondering if there is some way to configure authentication such
>   that users that have never logged in, actually get a login page... not
>   just the basic authentication prompt in the browser.

What's the login page do you mean?

1.If you mean the login page to connect to **TFS web portal**, as I know using basic prompt with `username+password` is the **only appraoch**.

Web Portal:

[image]

Only logic page:

[image]

2.But if you mean something used for authentication when accessing the code. I think you must be familiar with [PAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/auth-overview?view=azure-devops#personal-access-tokens) which is widely used in Azure Devops Service. IIS Basic Authentication is **not recommended**. You can check [Enabling IIS Basic Authentication invalidates using Personal Access Tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/iis-basic-auth?view=azure-devops) and [Use the TFS Cross Platform Command Line with TFS using basic authentication or personal access tokens (PATs)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/auth/tfs-basic-auth?view=azure-devops).

Hope it helps to resolve your puzzle :)

Comment: I believe I'm asking about the first thing. I want to authenticate against AD back-end, as it is working now, but to login I just get that browser prompt. I can't have it remember me, even for a short amount of time. I assumed devops server web ui would have some actual html based login page where I could check remember user etc.

Comment: I also noticed the logout functionality when configured this way, seems very buggy. Sometimes it sends you to a you are logged out screen and you can click login, and it'll send you right back to where you were without needing login. Sometimes it redirects you to a page that presents a ton of raw json

Comment: According to the documentation: "With Azure DevOps Server, you connect to an intranet server (for example, https://tfs.corp.contoso.com:8080/tfs). You authenticate with Windows Authentication and your Active Directory (AD) domain credentials. This process is transparent and you never see any kind of sign in experience."

Kind of sucks when you are trying to log in as a user that differs from the machine login.

Comment: Hmm, maybe I misunderstood your issue last time. If you're meaning the AD account, you can check [this similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22792865/can-i-add-active-directory-to-team-foundation-server-afterwards) for some help.

Answer (score 0):

So after lots of research, I found that in the differences between azure devops server and azure devops services documentation. In this documentation it states that it uses windows authentication, and you will never be presented with any login experience.

I'd vote that this should be something that be configured to show a login screen, as sometimes we want to log in as users other than the users we logged into the machine as.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution here, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.